# Returning mysqli_fetch_object from php function, on while it works continously

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating functions for database query:

```
function my_db_query($query_data) {
    $db_query = mysqli_query($query_data, $db_connection) or die(mysqli_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($db_query) > 0) {
        return mysqli_fetch_object($db_query);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

AND

```
function article( $ID='' ) {
    $db_query_string = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE id='".$ID."'";
    $db_query = my_db_query($db_query_string);
    return $db_query;
}
```

but when I call the function

```
while($content = article(5)) {
    echo $content->title;
}
```

it shows the title continuously and the PHP doesn't stop running.

How to make it stop? Because it is not like when I run `while ($content = mysqli_fetch_object($db_query))`.

PS: there could be more than one row with id 5 in database.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use logical opeartor in `while` statement

Comment: if you're expecting one record, do not loop. If you're expecting multiple records, you need to fetch them one by one. Your function will *always* return record 5 if it exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the design of your `my_db_query()`. Your function makes an SQL query and returns a single result. Every time you call your function it makes a new query that doesn't know about the previous queries, so it will return the same result as before. You need to separate the query and the fetch operations. In other words: Just remove your `my_db_query()` function and use the functions provided by PHP.

Edit.

Another option: fetch all your rows at once and loop through them.

```
function my_db_query($query_data) {
    $db_query = mysqli_query($query_data, $db_connection) or die(mysqli_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($db_query) > 0) {
                    // return all rows at once
        return mysqli_fetch_all($db_query);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function article( $ID='' ) {
    $db_query_string = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE id='".$ID."'";
    $db_query = my_db_query($db_query_string);
    return $db_query;
}

    $articles = article(5);
    // loop through the articles.
foreach($articles as $content) {
    echo $content->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of infinite loop. According to your code It will return only one result infinite time.

You called function `article` with argument `5` which return always true. Instead of while you have to use `IF` statement like

```
if($content = article(5)) {
    echo $content->title;
}
```

Comment: I'm using while because there could be more than one row in database with ID 5.

Comment: this may not help, as OP asked "there could be more than one row with id 5 in database".

Answer (score 0):

```
if($content = article(5)) {
    echo $content->title;
}
```

? You're making the query in an infinite loop, the query while be replayed each time and result may never be none if an article with ID=5 exists

EDIT: i've just seen the other answer, well, you've to review your database, an ID is supposed to be unique, or use a tuple key

EDIT2: you can use an if statement, and your 'article' function can return an array with all the rows

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($content = article(5))
```

This will be executed in every single loop iteration! `article(5)` will be called again and again in every loop iteration. It queries the database again and again and returns a new result object every time. It simply doesn't work like that. You can't bury the call to `mysqli_fetch_object` three layers deep in function calls; you have to call `mysqli_fetch_object` directly in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try in simple:

```
<?php
$db_query_string = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE id=5";
$db_query = mysqli_query($db_query_string, $db_connection) or die(mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($db_query) > 0) {
    while ($content = mysqli_fetch_object($db_query)) {
        echo $content->title;
    }
}
```